# how to use wait in C

Tags: c, wait

How do i use `wait` ? It just baffles me to no end. I `fork` a tree of procs with recursion and now the children have to pause(wait/sleep) while I run pstree so I can print the proc tree.

Should i use

```
int status;
wait(&status);
```

or rather

```
wait(NULL)
```

and where should i put this? in the parent `if(pid > 0)` or in the children `if(pid==0)`? Maybe at the end of ifs, so I store all the `pid`s in array and then run a `for` over them and use wait?

my code template:

```
void ProcRec(int index)
{
     pid_t pid;
     int noChild = getNChild(index);

     int i= 0;
     for(i = 0; i < noChild; i++)
     { 
          pid = fork();

        if (pid > 0)
        {
            /* parent process */
        }
        else if (pid == 0)
        {
            /* child process. */
            createProc(index+1);
        }
        else
        {
            /* error */
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    if(getpid() == root)
    {
        sleep(1); 
        pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0)
          execl("/usr/bin/pstree", "pstree", getppid(), 0);    
    }
}
```

Comment: `sleep(/*How many seconds do you want to wait*/);`.
`sleep(1);` wait for 1 second.

Comment: These are some links that will help you better understand how fork() and wait() work. Have a look at them and come back to your question. If doesn't help , then ask for help http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/wait.html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210638/working-of-fork-in-c-language , http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/create.html

Comment: Read the [`wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) and [`sleep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) manual pages. I'm sure you will find the difference pretty quickly.

Comment: I understand how `fork` works. I also differentiate between `sleep` and `wait`. What i don't know is what `int status` is, when to use `status` or when to `NULL `and where should i `wait`so i can use `pstree`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [`wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) system-call puts the process to sleep and waits for a child-process to end. It then fills in the argument with the exit code of the child-process (if the argument is not `NULL`).

So if in the parent process you have

```
int status;
if (wait(&status) >= 0)
{
    if (WIFEXITED(status))
    {
        /* Child process exited normally, through `return` or `exit` */
        printf("Child process exited with %d status\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
    }
}
```

And in the child process you do e.g. `exit(1)`, then the above code will print

```
Child process exited with 1 status
```

---

Also note that it's important to wait for all child processes before the parent process ends. Child processes that you don't wait for will be in a so-called zombie state while the parent process is still running, and once the parent process exits the child processes will be orphaned and made children of process 1.

Comment: @user2202368 Then you don't care about the status, you just wait for a child process to exit.

Comment: how do you wait for more than one child?

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu The `wait` waits for the *first* child.