# Is calling `wait` with an uninitialized value undefined behavior?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

```
int number;

// In some process

wait(&number);
```

Im doing a wait call on a process and want to know if this is safe or will I get undefined behavior?.

Comment: Depends whether `wait` expect a valid value, or if it is an out parameter.

Comment: [`wait`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) waits for a forked process to exit, so if you've forked a process, then yes it's safe. Or did you mean another `wait`?

Comment: If `number` is in scope, why would it be undefined behavior?

Comment: No the variable is not initialized

Comment: For the `wait()` system call, this would be normal usage and there's no UB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use wait in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709888/how-to-use-wait-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

If by `wait` you mean the syscall [`wait`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) that waits for a forked process to exit, then this is safe to do so. `number` can be uninitialized because `wait` will store the status in that variable.

If you are talking about another `wait` function, then I cannot tell you without looking at the source code of that `wait` function.

Answer (score 1):

This is safe because you're passing the address of a variable to a function.  While `number` was not initialized, its address has a well defined value.  So the function can safely take that address, dereference it, and write a value there, which is exactly what `wait` does.

The [man page for `wait`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) states:

> ```
> pid_t wait(int *status);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> If status is not NULL, wait() and waitpid() store status information
>   in
>          the int to which it points.

You would only have undefined behavior if you attempted to *read* the value of `number` before it is written to, and only if the stored value is a trap representation (i.e. doesn't represent a "real" value).