# fork() in C; which should be parent process which should be child process

Tags: c, multiprocessing, fork

This may seem to be a dumb question but I don't really have a good understanding of `fork()` other than knowing that this is about multi-threading. Child process is like a thread. If a task needs to be processed via `fork()`, how to correctly assign tasks to parent process and child process?

Comment: This question has been asked a million times. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210638/working-of-fork-in-c-language

Comment: Also, forking is *not* about multi-threading, it's about creating new *processes*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) which has an entire chapter dedicated to processes (because `fork` is difficult to explain);

then read documentation of [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html); [fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29) is not about [multi-threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29#Multithreading), but about creating [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29). Threads are generally created with [pthread_create(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) (which is implemented above [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html), a Linux specific syscall). Read some [pthreads tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) to learn more about threads.

PS. `fork` is *difficult* to understand (you'll need hours of reading, some experimentation, perhaps using [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), till you reach the "AhAh" [insight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insight) moment when you have understood it) since it returns twice on success. You need to keep its result, and you need to test the result for the three cases : <0 (failure), ==0 (child), >0 (parent). Don't forget to later call [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) (or something similar) in the parent, to avoid having [zombie processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process).

Answer (score 1):

Check the return value of `fork`. The child process will receive the value of `0`. The parent will receive the value of the process id of the child.